# Copying File Failed - UnityEngine.Purchasing.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have transferred my project from Windows system to my iMac and try to export iOS build.

When there is a build process started on the spot, I was started getting this kind of error:

[image]

Also within Temp -> StagingArea folder file is displaying in the locked state.

[image]

Now give me some suggestion into this so I can export iOS build for my project.

Comment: You can delete the folders `/TMP` and `/Library` unity will recreate them when you restart. (Make a backup first :))

Comment: @LudovicFeltz this worked for me - can you please post this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are copying a Unity project their is two folders that are auto-generated by Unity and can be deleted (it also help freeing a lot of space).

You can safely delete the folders `/TMP` and `/Library` Unity will recreate them automatically when you restart it.

Comment: If become possible then don't write a general statement - mention/write as an answer to the question...

Comment: @Siddharth I do not understand your comment. If this answer solve your problem (i think it does) just accept this answer.

Comment: You have written all general sentences, write sentences like you are answering the question otherwise people get confused.